# Getting a button by it's textContent, and making it hide/show certain divs onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter

I am creating some sort of filter in a webpage section.
when I **click** on a button, only the relatives **divs** should be shown.
The first script i made to make this work, was with one function for each button,
but since I'll have to add a lot more of buttons, I'd like to have only one function, and update it once added a new button.
here's a code similar to that part of the webpage.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script>
function filter1(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fruit");
     document.getElementById("all").onclick = function(){
     x.style.display = "block"
     };
     
     document.getElementById("apples").onclick = function(){
     x.style.display = "none"; document.getElementsByClassName(".apples").style.display = "block"
     };
     
     document.getElementById("lemons").onclick = function(){
     x.style.display = "none"; document.getElementsByClassName(".lemons").style.display = "block"
     };
     
}
function filter2(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn").onclick.textContent;
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("fruit");
if (x.toLowerCase().includes("all")) {
   y.style.display = "block";
} else {
    y.style.display = "none";
}
if (x.toLowerCase().includes("apples")) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("apples").style.display = "block";
}
if (x.toLowerCase().includes("lemons")) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("lemons").style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="filter1()">
 
  <button id="all" class="btn">All</button>
  <button id="apples"class="btn">Apples</button>
  <button id="lemons"class="btn">Lemons</button>
  
 <section>
  <div class="apples fruit">Green Apple</div>
  <div class="apples fruit">Red Apple</div>
  <div class="lemons fruit">Yellow Lemon</div>
 </section>
 
 </body>
</html>

 <style type="text/css">
  .btn {
   display: block
   }
   .fruit {
   display: block
   }
</style>
```

`As you can see I thought of two different methods for this.
the first one "filter1()" by adding an id for each button;
the second one "filter2()" by cheching the **.textContent** propriety of the buttons.

None of these functions work,
Can someone please tell me what's the right way to do this using Javascript,
or what's wrong with this code?
I'd like to use the "filter2()" function, but if you can fix both of them, it would be great.

I'm a complete beginner to coding.
Thank you so much.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, the function does not work because as the error says: x is not defined. You can use 'this' instead. Also you use the function 'getElementsByClassName' but you don't have to include the . before. So 'classname' instead of '.classname'. At last, you add event handlers on to the element but don't remove it. Even if your second function would work, the handler of the first will still be fired.